# Store address as value and use it later on pointer

Tags: c, embedded

I'm trying to emulate a system that needs to copy data to a peripheral, bare metal, no OS.

The convention states that the copy function is a C-function which takes as the address of the peripheral an 8-bit address that is written to a certain register. The peripheral uses that internally. However, I'm simulating the thing in C and to test the full functionality I am doing something like the following MWE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){

    //stack-array to copy
    char array[4] = {3,32,-12,99};
    //naive emulation of the peripheral memory space
    char peripheral_array[4];

    //herein lies the address send as a value
    char address_reg = (char*)(peripheral_array);

    //assume this is the peripheral side
    //set ptr to the address of the peripheral_array
    char *ptr = (char*) address_reg;
    memcpy((void*)ptr,array,sizeof(char)*4);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I get `segmentation fault`.

- What's the issue at hand here?
- How can I store the pointer of array as a value, send it, recast it successfully as the address to an array and perform the `memcpy`?

Comment: I would change the `char` to `unsigned char` if it is representing peripheral address space.

Comment: Aside: you don't need to cast to `void*` with `(void*)ptr`, the point of the `void*` type for `memcpy` is that it accepts any pointer type.

Comment: Code will not compile. Is address_reg identical with address?

Comment: Are you sure adresses are using 8 bits ? That would mean that the maximum length of any program (code + data) is 256 bytes. I understand that the registers may be 8 bits. But that doesn't mean that the address space is 8 bits too. Compare `sizeof(char *)` with `sizeof(char)` (i.e. with 1). What do you get ?

Comment: Ctx, yes.Edited. You are right, addresses are not using 8-bit. From what I can tell, 32-bits are being used. Maybe a better solution would be to define an 8-bit memory addressing space with 1 byte words. Then the address would be an offset to a certain base address of the peripheral, yet to the C function is a 'fully qualified address' to another memory space, or at least act like one.

Comment: @JoaoAndrade as described in the answer below, this code is wrong: `char address_reg = (char*)(peripheral_array);`.  That code tries to stuff the 4 bytes of data in `peripheral_array` as a `char *` into the **one-byte** `char address_reg`.  It doesn't fit.

Comment: It now seems that `char array[4] = {3,32,-12,99};` (which should be `unsigned char`) represents a 32-bit address, but it's still not clear whether each byte needs to be written to the same peripheral address, or to 4 consecutive addresses.

Comment: @AndrewHenle sometimes it can be required to write all the values to the same register in a particular sequence.

Comment: @WeatherVane - True, but that's not what the (currently) posted code is doing.  It's trying to put the (presumed) 4-byte address of `peripheral_array` into a `char`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to emulate something with a 8-bit address space in an environment with a 32-bit or 64-bit address space, and thus you have some difficulties, because it doesn't convert trivially. Specifically, this line `char address_reg = (char*)(peripheral_array)` cast a wide pointer to a 8-bit value, and lose most of the pointer, which means you won't be able to convert back.

The solution is to push further your simulation and emulate your destination 8-bit address space :

- Typedef a 8-bit pointer (cleaner) : `typedef uint8_t ptr8;`
- Declare your 8-bit destination address space : `uint8_t my_destination_memory[256]`
- Define you own memcpy to copy to this address space :

  ```
  void my_memcpy( ptr8 addr_dest, const void * src, int len ) {
      memcpy( my_destination_memory + addr_dest, src, len );
  }
  ```

This way you can pass around your 8-bit pointer of type `ptr8` (or whatever you name it) and copy to it without problem.
Note that I assumed that your source address space is not of importance, buti f it is you can also emulate it. You should be able to emulate 16-bit or even 24-bit address space in the same way (You can use the native pointers if you need 32-bit).

Comment: Will pursue this one.

Answer (score 1):

why storing it into `char`? the variable that can hold an address to a `char` is a `char*` - On Both machines - your PC and your embedded MCU!

On your MCU `sizeof(char*)` may be 1 or 2, and on your PC it may be 4 or 8;

If you want to write platform compatible code, use a `char*`.

If you want to go a few steps further to simulating the machines address space then you have to provide own implementations of the standard-lib functions. So that they interpret addresses in machines address space as indices to some some memory array that you defined.

However the better approach is mostly to provide some Hardware Abstraction Layer (HAL) that encapsulates system specific tasks, rather than using machine specifica in your business logic.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please note that storing integer values in the `char` type is dangerous, since it is a type with implementation-defined signedness. It should never be used for anything but strings.

Instead, always use either `int8_t` (signed) or `uint8_t` (unsigned).

---

The cause of the problem is that a `char` (or an `int8_t` for that matter) is not large enough to hold an address.

There is however the `uintptr_t` in `stdint.h` which is guaranteed to be large enough to contain an address.

Simply replace

```
char address_reg = (char*)(peripheral_array);
```

with

```
uintptr_t address_reg = (uintptr_t)peripheral_array;
```